# TSQL-How to replace null values of a column with the output of a join query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, case

Below query gives expected null values in some records under column Variable2

```
select SUBSTRING([Variable2],11,10), (select
Case
When Variable1 IS NULL Then 'ANSWERED NO'
When Variable1 = 'Confirmed' Then 'CONFIRMED'
When Variable1 = 'Cancelled' Then 'CANCEL'
END) from t1 
where DialedNumberString in (20062,20063,20065)
and DateTime between CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) and getdate()
and Variable1 IN ('Confirmed','Cancelled'))
UNION ALL
(select SUBSTRING([AccountNumber],11,10),(select
Case
When CallResult = 2 Then 'END DIAL TIM'
When CallResult = 6 Then 'BUSY'
When CallResult = 8 Then 'NO ANSWER'
When CallResult = 9 Then 'HANG UP'
END As CallStatus ) from t2
where DateTime between CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) and getdate() 
and CampaignID in (5004,5011,5012)
and QueryRuleID in (5016,5020,5021)
```

Now I am looking for an output where the above null values can be replaced from the output of the below join query in order. Note: Variable2 in table 't1' is same as AccountNumber in table 't2' but Variable2 has nulls for some reason (probably App workflow is designed that way).

```
Select d.AccountNumber as Variable2
from t1 r
LEFT JOIN t2 d ON r.RouterCallKey=d.RouterCallKey
where r.Variable2 is null and r.DialedNumberString in (20062,20063,20065)
and d.CampaignID in (5004,5011,5012) and d.QueryRuleID in (5016,5020,5021) 
and r.DateTime between CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) and getdate()
and d.DateTime between CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) and getdate()
```

Comment: You could just wedge an `ISNULL` in there, but I doubt it'll be performant.

Answer (score 0):

Removed 'When Variable1 IS NULL Then 'ANSWERED NO'' and did a UNION ALL with the join query adding the last column as 'ANSWERED NO'.

```
select SUBSTRING([Variable2],11,10), (select
Case
When Variable1 = 'Confirmed' Then 'CONFIRMED'
When Variable1 = 'Cancelled' Then 'CANCEL'
END) from t1 
where DialedNumberString in (20062,20063,20065)
and DateTime between CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) and getdate()
and Variable1 IN ('Confirmed','Cancelled'))
UNION ALL
(select SUBSTRING([AccountNumber],11,10),(select
Case
When CallResult = 2 Then 'END DIAL TIM'
When CallResult = 6 Then 'BUSY'
When CallResult = 8 Then 'NO ANSWER'
When CallResult = 9 Then 'HANG UP'
END As CallStatus ) from t2
where DateTime between CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) and getdate() 
and CampaignID in (5004,5011,5012)
and QueryRuleID in (5016,5020,5021)
UNION ALL
Select SUBSTRING([AccountNumber],11,10),'ANSWERED NO'
from t1 r
LEFT JOIN t2 d ON r.RouterCallKey=d.RouterCallKey
where r.Variable2 is null and r.DialedNumberString in (20062,20063,20065)
and d.CampaignID in (5004,5011,5012) and d.QueryRuleID in (5016,5020,5021) 
and r.DateTime between CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) and getdate()
and d.DateTime between CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) and getdate()
```